# Opencart You don't have permission to access /admin/index.php on this server

Tags: opencart

I have a problem when I click on "save" button in opencart "admin->system->setting", the error is:

```
Forbidden, You don't have permission to access /admin/index.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What can I do to correct this error?

Comment: go to system >> users >> user group and set administrative permission

Comment: I did it but no changes

Answer (score 1):

**Go to your project directory and right click admin folder and then click on Get Info**:

[image]

**After that double click on Lock icon and change the access to Read & Write**

[image]
**And then save the changes**

[image]

**Now refresh the url in browser your issue will be solved**

** -> It's mac setup may be window will be same**

Answer (score 0):

Check for the server mod security rules. (this worked for me)
Check from the install.txt file from the Opencart upload folder for the permissions and apply those in the appropriate place.